pgpool to not allow connections when standby server fail?
The scenario is the following: A postgresql cluster with a primary and a standby server.
Pgpool not working correctly when standby postgreSQL 14 server goes down, pgpool blocks all connections even though the primary server is working correctly.
This behavior is unacceptable since even though the primary works correctly, the prosgresql cluster is not accessible.
Causing the entire database failure.
Pgpool should still run and work against the primary server. If the remote commit is enabled,in each query, set the remote commit to off.
